# Appending Scraped Data to Dataframe - Python, Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm learning webscraping and working on Eat24 (Yelp's website). I'm able to scrape basic data from Yelp, but unable to do something pretty simple: append that data to a dataframe. Here is my code, I've notated it so it should be simple to follow along.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#go to eat24, type in zip code 10007, choose pickup and click search

driver.get("https://new-york.eat24hours.com/restaurants/index.php")
search_area = driver.find_element_by_name("address_auto_complete")
search_area.send_keys("10007")
pickup_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='search_form']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")
pickup_element.click()
search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search_form']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/button")
search_button.click()


#scroll up and down on page to load more of 'infinity' list

for i in range(0,3):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 
document.body.scrollHeight);")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0);")
    time.sleep(1)

#find menu urls

menu_urls = [page.get_attribute('href') for page in 
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@title="View Menu"]')]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'menuitems'])

#collect menu items/prices/name from each URL
for url in menu_urls:
    driver.get(url)
    menu_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cpa")
    menu_items = [x.text for x in menu_items]
    menu_prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item_price')
    menu_prices = [x.text for x in menu_prices]
    name = driver.find_element_by_id('restaurant_name')
    menuitems = dict(zip(menu_items, menu_prices))
    df['name'] = name
    df['menuitems'] = menuitems

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

The problem is at the end. It isn't adding menuitems + name into successive rows in the dataframe. I have tried using .loc and other functions but it got messy so I removed my attempts. Any help would be appreciated!!

Edit: The error I get is "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" when the for loop attempts to add a second set of menuitems/restaurant name to the dataframe

Comment: what is `pd` in `pd.DataFrame`? it's not defined in fragment you posted

Comment: @KirilS. `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Sorry yes I added that to the beginning, edited. Thanks for catching that

Comment: Shouldn't you have a third column for `menu_prices`, or maybe join the items in `menuitems`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a simple solution, not sure why I didn't think of it before. I added a "row" count that goes up by 1 on each iteration, and used .loc to place data in the "row"th row

```
row = 0
for url in menu_urls:
    row +=1
    driver.get(url)
    menu_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cpa")
    menu_items = [x.text for x in menu_items]
    menu_prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item_price')
    menu_prices = [x.text for x in menu_prices]
    name = driver.find_element_by_id('restaurant_name').text
    menuitems = [dict(zip(menu_items, menu_prices))]
    df.loc[row, 'name'] = name
    df.loc[row, 'menuitems'] = menuitems
    print df
```